# Как получить список аргументов функции?

Tags: php

Задача: нужно получить список (или количество) аргументов у функции (вне функции).

Существует ли некая функция

```
int/array get_function_args(string $fname)
```

которая бы возвращала количество аргументов, либо массив имен аргументов функции?
Сначала нашел *func_ get_ args()*, но это не та функция, т.к. работает внутри функции.

Если такого способа не существует, то отпадает очень красивое решение одной задачи :( ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не подходит [Класс ReflectionParameter](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.reflectionparameter.php)?

Comment: Однозначно плюсик, забыл про reflection, поэтому пришел в голову такой срам :facepalm:  

    define (WARNING,E_USER_NOTICE);
    $counter=0;
    $x=function($a, $b){return 666;};

    function myErrorHandler ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
        global $counter;
        $counter++;
    };
    set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
    function funcParams($func){
        global $counter;
        $func();
        echo $counter;
    };
    funcParams($x);

Comment: Бро, спасибо, похоже, это то, что надо...